# AppLovin FullScreen ad not working in Cocos2d iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, cocos2d-iphone, applovin

I followed AppLovin sdk integration guide from here: https://www.applovin.com/integration

Code:

```
[ALSdk initializeSdk];
[ALInterstitialAd showOver:viewController.view.window];
```

Not getting this part of Doc:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working now. All that we need to do is add right bundle id and AppLovinSDKKey in info.plist

[image]